# C# How to create a zip file from 3 directory contents

Tags: c#, zip

pseudo code:
c:\temp\Backup.zip = (c:\Temp\Config*.* , c:\Temp\Data*.*, c:\Temp\scripts*.*)

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you reasearch C# API's?

Comment: System.IO.Compression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try **DotNetZip library**. [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)

Here is a very simple example:

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile();
zipFile.AddFile("{path}/file.txt");
zipFile.Save("{path}/filename.zip");
zipFile.Dispose();
```

For doing this with files in a directory you can use

```
string [] files = Directory.GetFiles("directoryPath", "*.txt");
```

And add to zipFile instance each file in the array. **Notice: Second parameter in Directory.GetFiles function is the search pattern**

Comment: By the way, DotNetZip is available in NuGet